# Change a SpreadSheet Name via a cell reference - Google Sheets / Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like a cell reference to change a SpreadSheet Name with script ?

The name of the SpreadSheet is **KIT MAKING MACRO** and I would like O1(**A90241 - Batch 3**) cell to change its name to.

See below image to see what I mean.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change Google Sheets file name based on cell information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55695863/how-to-change-google-sheets-file-name-based-on-cell-information)

Answer (score 1):

To do this you will need to create a reference to the spreadsheet as a [`File`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file) using [`DriveApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app). Once you have the file object call [`setName`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#setName(String)) to change the name to whatever you want.

```js
var spreadSheet = SpreadSheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadSheet.getActiveSheet();
var newName = sheet.getRange(sheet.getName() + "!O1") // get the range of the cell
    .getValues()[0]; // retrieve the values and take the first (only) value

var file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadSheet.getid());

file.setName(newName);
```